# Can i Run two ant tasks at the same time?

Tags: ant

i want to reduce the build time taken for a build by excecuting  as many independent tasks at the same time as possible. is it possible to do it?

I have tried using parallel tasks in the targets but parallel task will only parallelise within a target.i didnt get any significant build time reduction with parallel tasking.so now i am want to run entire targets in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Ant supports parallel tasks. See this documentation: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html

Comment: Just be sure to not miss the warning:

> Warning: While the Apache Ant core is believed to be thread safe, no such guarantees are made about tasks, which are not tested for thread safety during Ant's test process. Third party tasks may or may not be thread safe, and some of Ant's core tasks, such as <javac> are definitely not re-entrant. This is because they use libraries that were never designed to be used in a multithreaded environment.